# Ошибка в запуске python в wsl через pycharm: CreateProcess error=1921, Имя этого файла не может быть разрешено системой

Tags: python, windows-10, pycharm, wsl

Скачал подсистему Ubuntu 20.04 для windows 10, следуя этому [туториалу](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#simplified-installation-for-windows-insiders) (Simplified Installation), а затем настроил интерпретатор pycharm по [туториалу](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html).

После запуска файла .py любого содержания вылетает ошибка (CreateProcess error=1921, имя этого файла не может быть разрешено системой). Переустановка WSL не помогла, создание новой virtualenv так же не дало результатов. Если запускать скрипт через терминал, всё работает отлично. Ниже скрин интерпретатора и ошибки, а также выполнение скрипт в терминале.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!
[image: ошибка]

[image: интерпретатор]

[image: терминал]